# Implementing deepcopy on reshift

Tags: amazon-redshift, deep-copy

I am working on implementing deepcopy using python on redshift. I have a working script, if you pass the tables - it will deep copy. I am looking for

1. Criteria to determine what tables need to be deep copied
2. How do you determine what tables would you vacuum vs deep copy

Appreciate your inputs.

Comment: Unfortunately, your question contains very little detail about your usage of Redshift, the size of your tables and any problems you are currently experiencing. Therefore, it is not possible to offer any advice. For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Total space used on redshift : 200 TB, primary use is for doing ETL using custom SQL scripts. we have around 50 tables that are over 1 TB. Problems we are currently facing are - performance of our batch is incrementally getting worse because of the way redshift does deletes and updates. We have been using cluster resize as a proxy to get rid of rows marked for deletion. Right after the cluster resize performance gets better, but gets worse with time until next resize. we are planning to use vacuum and deepcopy, and i am looking for guidance on how you use one over other.

Comment: How frequently do you do vacuum and deep copy, best practices

Comment: There is [lots of advice](https://www.google.com/search?q=vacuum+redshift+best+practices) out there. Basically, if you are deleting a lot of rows, then use `VACUUM` to clean it up. If `VACUUM` runs too slowly, use a Deep Copy. You should not be using a cluster resize as a means of improving performance. Also, optimize tables by using `SORTKEY` and `DISTKEY` wisely.

Answer (score 0):

[Redshift Docs: "Performing a Deep Copy"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/performing-a-deep-copy.html)

You can also use our Python based ["Column Encoding Utility" (on GitHub)](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/tree/a36138f34052e3a6d9072a4da9e46107da4eacd0/src/ColumnEncodingUtility) to perform the deep copy.